# CA Clarity and TFS integration

Tags: tfs, integration, clarity

Has anybody was able to integrate CA Clarity PPM with Team foundation Server.
I need the ability to add work item from Clarity while TFS report item status to Clarity.
for long story short I am looking for a bidrictional integration tool between those two platforms.
Thanks
Erez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am checking a integration tool called TaskTop sync which suppose to provide the bidrictional integration.
see http://tasktop.com/sites/default/files/documents/TasktopSolutions-CertifiedConnectors.pdf

will keep posted if it works.

Erez

Comment: How did this end up working? I'm looking for a solution that has bi-directional support between TFS and Clarity. I'd like to create my project plan/tasks in Clarity and have them created in TFS to use for Agile then update time in TFS and have it interfaced back into Clarity.

Comment: we created a web service that triggered from clarity events and creates a TFS workitem accordengly. and the only thing that is bidirectional is precentage which updates the clarity